# Duda trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

es la primera vez que escribo aquí así que lo explicaré lo mejor posible. Tengo que crear un trigger para que que cada vez que se inserte un registro en la tabla pedidos, se actualice el stock(tabla libros) del libro vendido.

La BBDD sería tal que así :

[image: base de datos libreria]

Entiendo que si hago un insert en la tabla pedidos, para relacionarla con la tabla libros, debo pasar por la tabla lineas_pedido que es la que hace de "puente".

Yo he intentado hacer esto:

```
DELIMITER // 

CREATE TRIGGER practicaej2
AFTER INSERT ON pedidos 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- Declaro variables 
    DECLARE nuevocodigo varchar(20);
    DECLARE cuanto integer;
    DECLARE ncodPed varchar(20);
    DECLARE ncodLibro varchar(20);
-- Hace referencia a codigo de la tabla pedidos
    set nuevocodigo=new.codigo; 
-- Quiero el valor de cantidad cuando el codigo de pedidos tiene el valor de new.codigo para poder restarlo al stock
    set cuanto=(select cantidad from lineas_pedido inner join pedidos on lineas_pedido.codPedido=pedidos.codigo where codPedido=@nuevocodigo);
-- Quiero el valor del codPed de la tabla lineas_pedido para poder relacionar con la tabla libros
    set ncodPed=(select codPedido from lineas_pedido inner join pedidos on lineas_pedido.codPedido=pedidos.codigo where codPedido=@nuevocodigo);
-- Quiero el valor de codLibro para relacionarla con la tabla libros
    set ncodLibro=(select codLibro from lineas_pedido where codPedido=@ncodPed);
    

    UPDATE libros set stock=libros.stock-@cuanto where @ncodLibro=libros.codigo;
END;
//
```

Posiblemente este todo mal, pero no consigo entender como hacerlo de otra forma.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Todas las variables que obtienes están en la tabla `lineas_pedido`, también la columna del WHERE en la consulta UPDATE existe en esa tabla, entonces me pregunto ¿por qué no programas el TRIGGER directamente en esa tabla? Y, aunque fuera obligatorio hacerlo desde `pedidos` por un motivo justificado, podrías hacer el `UPDATE` directamente sin necesidad de lanzar N consultas para obtener N datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. El enunciado del ejercicio, me pide que cada vez que se inserte un pedido nuevo en la tabla pedidos, disminuya la cantidad de stock en la tabla libros del libro correspondiente. Creo que me estoy liando. Aun así gracias por responder, veré que puedo hacer!

Comment: Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo se actualiza `lineas_pedido`? No le veo sentido a poner un TRIGGER en una tabla para usar luego datos, los cuales están todos en otra tabla. Pero tratándose de un ejercicio, conviene que expliques con claridad las cosas y lo que te permiten o no te permiten hacer en el contexto del ejercicio.

Comment: Para que se actualice lineas_pedido, debo hacer un insert en dicha tabla, pero para ello tienen que estar los datos de su PK(de lineas_pedido) insertados ya en las otras tablas (libros y pedido). De hecho debería restarle al stock el valor de la columna cantidad de lineas_pedido. Perdona si no me explico bien. Yo tampoco encuentro mucho sentido.